# Loop through directory and save all faces in other directory

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to loop through all the images from the directory and save faces in other directory. This is my code.

```
cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"

# Create the haar cascade
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

import glob
files=glob.glob("*.jpg")
for file in files:

    # Read the image
    image = cv2.imread(file)
    print(file)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces in the image
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=4,
        minSize=(30, 30), flags = cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
    print ("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))

    # Crop Padding
    left = 10
    right = 10
    top = 10
    bottom = 10

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        print (x, y, w, h)

        image  = image[y-top:y+h+bottom, x-left:x+w+right]

        print ("cropped_{1}{0}".format(str(file),str(x)))
        cv2.imwrite("cropped_{1}_{0}".format(str(file),str(x)), image)
```

The above code expects the image to be in `jpg` format. It also retrieves the image from the root folder and saves in the root folder itself.
How can I loop through `test_input` directory and save all faces in `test_output` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through `test_input`, modify the string passed to `glob.glob`:

```
files = glob.glob("test_input/*.jpg")
```

To save to a particular output directory simply specify that directory when saving your image. Use `os.path.join` to join paths safely.

```
import os
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("test_output", "cropped_{1}_{0}".format(str(file),str(x))), image)
```